# Explain this bit of code

Tags: bash

Could somebody explain what this bit of code means please ?

I believe the second line is "if the exit status is zero", then echo "valid command" but I dont understand the first line

```
$@ &>/dev/null
if [[ $? = 0 ]]
then
   echo "Valid command"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to add that this is unnecessarily verbose and could be shortened to

```
if "$@" &>/dev/null
then
    echo "Valid command"
fi
```

or even shorter

```
"$@" &>/dev/null && echo "Valid command"
```

Answer (score 7):

The first line runs the command formed by simply using all arguments to the script, and redirecting the output to /dev/null which essentially throws it away.

The built-in variable [$@](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF2) expands to all of the positional parameters, with each parameter is a quoted string, i.e. the parameters are passed on intact, without interpretation or expansion. To get this effect, I believe you need to quote the use of the variable, i.e. say `"$@"`.

The operator `&>` redirects both stdout and stderr.

Comment: Just to support: explanation is found here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF

Comment: I think that `$*` and `$@` are only different when surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: @mkb: you are right. I fear @unwind is not: without specifing `"$@"`, the parameters would get whitespace split, i.e.
`function TT () { $@ ; } ;
TT ls 1 2 '3 4'`

Answer (score 4):

According to the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters), `$@` expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. If you call this script as `scripty.sh ls /`, it will execute `ls /` while redirecting all output to the bit bucket. That should return success (I hope!) and thus the script will print `Valid command`. If you call it `scripty.sh ls /some/nonexistent/directory` then the `ls` command should fail, and the script will output nothing.

Actually, I think the script can be improved to putting double quotes around `$@` so that arguments with spaces in them don't trip up the interpreter.

With `$@` the command `ls "/Library/Application Support"` is expanded to three words. With `"$@"` it's expanded to two, and the command is run just as it would be without the script wrapping it.